# How to access Realm data in .NET without syncing

Tags: .net, realm

I have a Realm cloud server up and running.
I have clients using full sync on their realms and some shared full sync realms also.

I want to make a .NET server that can query data from all realms, and create data in all realms.

Do I have to use a Realms.Sync.User and sync all data before I can work with the data, even if I am on the same server?

Can the .NET server code access all Realm data without syncing it?
What type of RealmConfiguration do I use in that case?

Basically I want to create something in .NET that works kind of like Realm Studio.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Realm Studio uses sync to pull the data locally and presents you with its local view of the data. Since that is undesirable for your use case, you can instead use the [GraphQL API](https://docs.realm.io/sync/graphql-web-access) to read/write data over HTTP without using sync.